There is no finalizer in the .NET Core HttpMessageInvoker
I have a question about the Disposable pattern at https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System/net/System/Net/Http/HttpMessageInvoker.cs.
As per the documentation of the Disposable patterns at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.gc.suppressfinalize?view=net-8.0, a proper disposable pattern should have a finalizer.
But in case of the HttpMessageInvoker, I find NO finalizers. I tried to look at different places for the source code and all of them shows the missing HttpMessageInvoker.
Can anybody shed some light here?

it doesn't have any unmanaged resources
